# install software package-centre app

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install the `software-centre` package on Terminal..

I have entered these commands:

`sudo apt-get install software-center*`

I get this:

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required
  thuderbird-global menu
use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

another

```
'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Avinash Raj  I am running 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 12.04, run these commands in Terminal:

> sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise precise-updates main universe multiverse restricted" > /etc/apt/sources.list
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get autoremove
>
> sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: I ran these comments on T, unfortunately I have the same result. "software-center" has no installation candidate.

Comment: I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Great Naveen, I am going to input that now.

Comment: It has come up with is quotation :"permission denied".  I rechecked spelling and so on.

Comment: You missed the part **sudo**. Just copy and paste lines directly on Terminal. Give the correct user password if prompted as well

Comment: I tried it all, even copy and paste, separately and altogether. It reads: some index files failed to download and a host of other stuff. if i enter the first line only it reads: permission denied.

Comment: Ok. Then execute this in your Terminal: `sudo passwd root`   Then you will be asked to set a password. Then execute : `su root` . Now you can execute all the commands above once again.